# Restriction of $T$-invariant measure is $T$-invariant.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $M$ be a compact metric space, and let $T$ be a homeomorphism $T \colon M \to M$.

We say measure $\mu$ on Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $T$-invariant if for every continuous function $f \colon M \to \mathbb{R}$, $\int_M f \circ T d\mu = \int_M f d\mu$.

Now let $\mu \colon M \to [0,1]$ be a $T$-invariant measure and fix Borel measurable $A$.

I want to show that $\mu_0(B) = \frac{\mu(B \setminus A)}{1-\mu(A)}$ and $\mu_1(B) = \frac{\mu(A \cap B)}{\mu(B)}$ are $T$-invariant.

It seems it would suffice to show that if $\mu$ is invariant, so is its restriction $\mu|A$.

But it seems

$\int f \circ T d(\mu|A) = \int_A f \circ T d\mu$, and it seems $\int_A f \circ T d\mu$ may not equal $\int_A f d\mu$ despite $\int_M f d\mu = \int_M f \circ T d\mu$.

The question comes from this proof where they claim $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ are $\phi$-invariant.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It might be better to give the reference for the excerpt for posterity.

Comment: @AlpUzman it's Functional Analysis by Buhler and Salamon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the subset you are conditioning on ought to be $T$-invariant as well; so that

$$\chi_{A}(x)\, f\circ T(x)=\chi_{T^{-1}(A)}(x)\, f\circ T(x) = \chi_A\circ T(x)\, f\circ T(x) = (\chi_A\, f)\circ T(x).$$

(Also the collection of measurable $T$-invariant subsets is a $\sigma$-algebra.)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point but $\chi_A f$ is not necessarily continuous, so I can't use that for all $f \in C(M)$, $\int_M f d \mu = \ int_M f \circ T d\mu$.

Comment: @Phil  A characterization of the $T$-invariance of $\mu$ is that the same integral equality holds for $f$ Borel measurable (by a standard approximation argument).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/984201/169085.